# How can I upload videos directly to Vimeo without uploading my server?

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have a website. In my website, users will upload videos. I get a Vimeo Pro account to store the videos. Now, the videos are stored form user end to the server. Then it uploads to Vimeo from the server. It takes twice the time to upload it to Vimeo.

So, I need a solution to upload the videos directly from the user's end. I don't want to upload the videos to my server. Is there any way to upload the videos directly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224970068-Can-I-upload-directly-to-Vimeo-and-skip-my-server-entirely-

Comment: You'll have to store the videos on your server, even if only for a short period of time, otherwise the users you'll have to upload the videos directly to vimeo. I'd create a script  that runs every x minutes and would re-upload the new videos to vimeo, that you can delete them. You can also use the upload script you already have and add some code to upload to vimeo and delete the local files.

Comment: Is there any way to upload the videos directly to Vimeo without uploading to my server first?

Answer (score 0):

To upload direct from the user/client browser, use the POST upload method and deploy the HTML form as documented here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#form-based

Uploads using the POST upload method will upload from the client browser direct to Vimeo, without uploading to your server. However, be aware that if the user leaves the page or loses internet connection the upload will fail and there is no way to resume the upload.